# Printing value stored in **char in C

Tags: c++, c, pointers

I am new to C and I do know concept of pointers a little bit bu when I see something like **char(Pointer to a pointer?) it confuses me. So I am looking at a function, definition of which looks like below:

```
void Settings_ParseCommandLine( int argc, char **argv, thread_Settings *mSettings )
```

Anyways, what I want at the moment is what is the value that *argv is holding. I would like to do Printf on it. How can I do that?

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3024197/what-does-int-argc-char-argv-mean

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`argv` is an array of strings.  `*argv` is equivalent to `argv[0]`, also known as the first string in `argv`.  You can just print it exactly as you suggest:

```
printf("%s\n", *argv);
```

If you want to print them all (which is probably more useful):

```
for (int i = 0; i < argc; i++)
    printf("%s\n", argv[i]);
```

Answer (score 4):

```
printf("%s\n", argv[0]);
```

or

```
printf("%s\n", *argv);
```

Be sure to check `argc` for number of entries in `argv`.

Answer (score 3):

If something is declared `char` it means it is an (usually) 8-bit character value.

If something is declared `char*` it means it's a pointer to a `char`.

If something is declared `char**` it means it's a pointer to a pointer to a `char`.

When you apply the `*` operator to a pointer in an expression, you "dereference" is and cause the value that the pointer points to to be returned.  If you apply `*` more than once presumably the thing you're applying it to is a pointer to a pointer.

In the above case the `char **argv` is a declaration of the `argv` parameter, defining it as a pointer to a pointer to `char`.

There are two other important things to understand.  First, a `sometype*` pointer may (or may not) be a pointer to an *array* of `sometype`, rather than a single `sometype` value.  (There is no way to know if this is the case other than to examine how the pointer was set.)

Second, an array of `char` values is the usual way that a "character string" is represented in C, and hence `char*` often addresses a character string.

By induction, then, `char**` *may* be a pointer to an array of pointers to character strings.

Answer (score 2):

In C we usually think of a `char *` as a string right?  So, think of `char **` as a pointer to a string, or a pointer to a char pointer.  This means that `argv` contains multiple strings (each of which should be null terminated).  `argc` tells you how many strings `argv` contains.

To print it, try something like this:

```
for (i = 0; i < argc; ++i)
  printf("%s ", argv[i])
```

Answer (score 0):

`char** argv` can be thought of as a pointer to a pointer, but it can also be thought of as an array of arrays. Since a string is an array of characters in C, `char**` points to an array of strings.

If you want to access arguments, you can do it like this:

```
// argv[0] is the executable name
char* first_arg = argv[1]; // argv[1] is the first argument and so on...
printf("first arg: %s\n", first_arg);
```

Make sure to use `argc` to check that you have enough arguments before you use them though :)

Comment: Not sure about 'array of arrays'; maybe 'start of an array of pointers' (or even just 'array of pointers')…The 'array of strings' is reasonable.